# PHP $stmt to get the right user

Tags: php

I made this more understandable what i want here, so:
I want to SELECT the users here that has the ,for example , "coder" in his "proffesion" field, in Mysql table. Because as you see here by this code it will pick a random user except the user who is logged in. And i need to make another condition after AND ( see the code line 2 ) so it FINDS and puts out only user with the "coder" written in proffesion field. What info do you need more to help to solve the problem?

ps. it should pick from column - PROFESSION

```
public function whoToFollow1($user_id, $profileID){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` != :user_id AND (what stetement need to be here)  ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array("user_id" => $user_id));       
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo '<div class="wrap"><div class="inner"><div class="title"></div>';
        foreach ($users as $user) {
```

Comment: What is the name of column is the coder is in?

Comment: the column is - profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the condition you described to the query i.e.

```
$profession = "coder";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` != :user_id AND profession = :profession  ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array("user_id" => $user_id, "profession" => $profession));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` != :user_id AND `profession`=:job ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->execute(array("user_id" => $user_id, "job" => $job));
```

Note: `$job` will be used to represent the current job you wish to target.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think `$stmt` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

```
// I am assuming you have profession table with id and profession name/type
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN profession on users.profession_id = profession.id
WHERE `user_id` = :user_id 
AND profession.id =  :profession_id
```